# ASP USER LOGIN SCRIPT

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

When i try to login with the below code it give me an error saying

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e10'.
>
> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> /ghbet/login2.asp, line 11

LOGIN1.ASP:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align=center>
            <tr>
                <td align=center>
                    <b> LOGIN </b>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <form action=login2.asp method=post>
                        UserName <input type=text name=uname /> <br>
                        Password <input type=password name=password /> <br><br>
                        <p align=right> <input type=submit value=LOGIN name=submit /> </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

LOGIN2.ASP:

```
<%
    dim name, pass
    name=Request.form("uname")
    pass=Request.form("password")

    set conn=server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    conn.ConnectionString="provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ghbet\ghbet.mdb"
    conn.Open
    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    query="select * from ghbet_users where username='" & name & "'and password='" & pass & "'"
    rs.Open query,conn

    if not rs.EOF  then 
        Response.Write " <h4> LOGIN SUCCESSFUL </h4>"
    else
        response.Write "<h4> USER NAME & PASSWORD NOT MATCHING </h4>"
    end if

%>vb
```

please help

Comment: check that "name" and "pass" are not empty before sending the query

Comment: i always make sure it's not empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sure way to get a "No value given for one or more required parameters." error is to ask for non-existing field(name)s. So check whether ghbet_users really has the fields username and password.

As Cheran pointed out, reserved words can cause problems. As nobody can know what words will be reserved in the next version of your DBMS, enclose **all** names in [].

You should seriously consider to use a parameter query to avoid SQL attacks and data type/quoting problems.

Your If clause accepts the loggin attempt, if "not rs.EOF" - i.e. if the query returns one **or more** records; you should test for one record containing the expected values.

Answer (score 2):

`PASSWORD` is a reserved Jet SQL keyword (see [List of Microsoft Jet 4.0 reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266)). Try surrounding the column name with square brackets `[]` in your query:

```
query="select * from ghbet_users where username='" & name& "'and [password]='" & pass & "'"
```

Comment: Taking reserved words into accound is valid/important advice - even if - as in this case - there are many more ways to mess things up.

Comment: Is renaming the database column an option?  Also, have you tried adding Response.Write Query just before where you try to execute your query, it really helps when debugging

Comment: can you give me a sample of that(response.write) since i'm new to asp

Comment: If you enter the line "Response.Write query" on a line immediately above "rs.Open query,conn" then the SQL query you're trying to execute will be displayed with the parameters you've sent in your form.  It's not something you'd want to leave in when the website is live, but when you start getting error messages which say something is wrong with your SQL it's useful to be able to view the SQL it doesn't like

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the string you are assigning to the query is the root of this error message. Make sure you provide spaces between the variable you are concatenating in the string.

The first thing I would do is make sure that the parameters contain values, make sure that when the form is posted, it passes the values of "name" and "password".

Comment: i make sure i don't send an empty string, but still doesn't work